# How to go back to the same JSP page in Spring MVC with the same values

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Please help me on this. Below is my LoginController class where I pass the username and password from a JSP and then validate and display the to do list of the username in diffrent jsp page.

Here is my code

LoginController.class

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/loginvalidate")
  public String validatelogin(LoginForm request, ModelMap map) throws Exception {
    String userName = request.getUserName();
    sessionUser.setUserName(userName);
    map.addAttribute("user", sessionUser.getUserName());
    map.addAttribute("dateTime", sessionscopebillingdata.getDate());
    System.out.println("username from the controller class " + sessionUser.getUserName());
    List result = loginservice.ValidateLogin(request);
    map.addAttribute("ToDoList", result);
    return "UserToDoList";
 }
```

Here is my UserToDoList.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
<div class="inset">
    <%=session.getAttribute("dateTime")%>
    <h2> TO DO LIST </h2>        
    <%=session.getAttribute("user")%>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>    
<body>
    <form action="logout" method="POST">
        <button type="submit">Logout</button>    
    </form>        

    <form name="Add" action="Adduser" method="post">
        <button type="submit">ADD</button> 

    </form>
    </link>
    <form:form>

        <c:if test="${not empty ToDoList}">

            <table>

                <tr><th>LOGIN ID</th>
                    <th>LAST UPDATE BY</th>
                    <th>TRANSACTION TYPE</th>
                    <th>STATUS</th>
                </tr>    
                <c:forEach var="item" items="${ToDoList}">
                    <tr>   <td>${item[0]}</td>
                        <td>${item[1]}</td>
                        <td>${item[2]}</td>   
                        <td>${item[3]}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>

            </table>

        </c:if>


    </form:form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

From the above JSP if I click the "Add" button  then it will goes to the below JSP

AddUser.jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" name="LoginForm" modelAttribute="roleId" action="adduser"> 
 <ul>
    <li>
        <label>User Name</label> <input type="text" name="userName" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Password</label> <input type="text" name="passWord" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Approver </label> <input type="text" name="approver" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>User Role </label>
        <form:select path="userRole" items="${Codes}" tabindex="50">
            <form:option value="----------Please select---------" />
            <form:option value="${role.id}" />
            <form:option value="${role.codeValue}" /> 
        </li>
    </form:select>
  </ul>  


 <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form:form>
```

From the above JSP if click submit then it will call the below method inside the same Logincontroller class and this is to add new users .

Once new user added I want this method to go back to the same "UserToDoList.jsp" with the same output.
How to achieve this , Please help.

Below method is from LoginController.class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adduser")
public String adduser(LoginForm request) throws Exception {
    String result = loginservice.adduser(request);
    return "/Adduser";
 }
```

Below id my bean to get the username

```
@Component
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)

public class BillingSessionScopeUser {

public String userName;

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
```

}

Comment: You need to add `@ModelAttribute("LoginForm")` to your `LoginForm` method argument. You shouldn't use that to pass along the information. You already have a session scoped object which you should use in both controllers.

Comment: And ... what is sessionUser ? Is it part of the HttpSession ?

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, I have done public String validatelogin(@ModelAttribute("LoginForm")LoginForm request, ModelMap map) is this correct ? how can i keep my model attributes also ? basically I want to show the same view of UserToDoList.jsp again when i return the  Adduser from adduser method

Comment: @SergeBallesta , I have added my bean class BillingSessionScopeUser.class and I Autowired this in my controller class private BillingSessionScopeUser sessionUser; and annotated using scope("session")
SessionAttributes({"user","dateTime"})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should clearly separate the login phase from the todo list extraction. It could look like :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginvalidate")
public String validatelogin(LoginForm request, ModelMap map, Session session) throws Exception {
    String userName = request.getUserName();
    sessionUser.setUserName(userName);
    map.addAttribute("user", sessionUser.getUserName());
    map.addAttribute("dateTime", sessionscopebillingdata.getDate());
    System.out.println("username from the controller class " + sessionUser.getUserName());
    // BEGIN CHANGE
    List result = loginservice.getTodoList(userName);
    //END CHANGE
    map.addAttribute("ToDoList", result);
    return "UserToDoList";
}
```

Then in the `POST` part for `adduser`, you could have :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adduser")
public String adduser(@ModelAttribute LoginForm request, ModelMap model) throws Exception {
    String result = loginservice.adduser(request);
    String userName = sessionUser.getUserName();
    List result = loginservice.getTodoList(userName);
    map.addAttribute("ToDoList", result);
    map.addAttribute("user", userName);
    map.addAttribute("dateTime", sessionscopebillingdata.getDate());
    return "UserToDoList"; // ensure correct name for view
 }
```

Alternatively, you could try to rebuild a `LoginForm` from `sessionUser` (and eventually other session scoped beans), say `sessionRequest` and directly use :

```
List result = loginservice.ValidateLogin(sessionRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks it's working after I separated the validation and the to do list method.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adduser")
public String adduser(LoginForm request) throws Exception {
String result = loginservice.adduser(request);
return "UserToDoList";
}
```

return the file name which you want to show when you click on add button.

Comment: Hi sorry it was my error I have returned the file what u said but still my list inside the jsp is null .

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/adduser" @ModelAttribute("roleId") BillingSessionScopeUser billingSessionScopeUser) here you will get username value if you want password,approver and userRole then you should declare in model class BillingSessionScopeUser then you will get all value in object of class in above line.

Comment: you can check String userName = billingSessionScopeUser.getUserName() and you have to add result in map and that you have to access in jsp.